# How to proxy all requests to localhost using nginx and plesk?

Tags: nginx, centos, plesk, nuxt.js

I need to deploy a Nuxt.js SSR web application on a centos server. Plesk control panel is already on the server so I need to proxy all requests from `example.com` to `localhost:3000` except plesk control panel which is `example.com:8443` and an API URL which is `example.com/api/v1` (API is in the WWW folder). The Web server used is nginx.

I tried to use nginx proxy mode, but then I can't get access to API or plesk control panel anymore.

I expect to have 3 vhosts on one IP:

1. `www.example.com` for web application
2. `www.example.com:8443` for plesk control panel
3. `www.example.com/api/v1` for API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those with the same problem. this is how i solved it:
go to Plesk control panel/ websites and domain/ Apache and Nginx settings
in `Additional Apache directives` section you can add your apache code:

```html
<Location />
 ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
 ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
</Location>

<Location /API/>
 ProxyPass !
</Location>
```